# Index of available user-only pages to a user

Tags: webflow

I'm building a site to sell online courses. For each course, I've created a purchasable access group. When a user purchases "Course A", that purchase gives their user account permission to visit the "Course A" page. Same for course B. If they purchase both courses with the same user account, they are able to access both pages.

I want to create a "My Courses" page which lists each page they have access to. So if the user has purchased "Course A", only that one is listed and can be clicked. If they have bought both courses, both are listed.

Any advice on how to create this "My Courses" page? Thank you. Will buy coffee.